# Open CWD in File Explorer | 20.04 LTS on Windows 10

Tags: 20.04, windows, windows-10

How do I open CWD in file explorer, Windows?

I have tried the following lines but without luck:

```
open .

explorer .

open() {
  explorer.exe `wslpath -w "$1"`
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To open the current working directory from WSL in the host's Windows Explorer, you can use:

```
explorer.exe "$(wslpath -w "$PWD")"
```

More generally, a shell function to open a given directory may be written as

```
weopen() { explorer.exe "$(wslpath -w "$1")"; }
```

You can then use

```
weopen .
```

to open the current directory, `.`

Answer (score 1):

Found a work around way.

Open File Explorer locations, and type "bash" into directory bar.

Then in each bash window, type:

```
echo $PWD
```

Copy and paste this output (paste into terminal by right-clicking).

then in the one you want to copy to:

```
cp <source/nameoffile> <location>
```